# Can I fill the 'about me' section from the Android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, tour

I think the question is quite clear. I cannot find where can I can fill the 'about me' section from Android app.

Comment: No, you can't. And it's already asked to add such a feature, hence closing as duplicate.